# Netty 4.0 LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder Not Working

Tags: netty

We have a socket client program written in c#, and I'm trying to rewrite it with Netty. The c# login method looks like this:

```
public bool login(String prefix, string username, string password)
    {
        Send(String.Format("{0}{1},{2}\n", prefix, username, password));

        try
        {
            var _4B = new byte[4];
            _socket.Receive(_4B, 4, SocketFlags.None);
            var len = ConvertToInteger(_4B);
            var b = new byte[len];
            _socket.Receive(b, len, SocketFlags.None);
            GZipStream stream = new GZipStream(new MemoryStream(b, 0, len), CompressionMode.Decompress);
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.GetEncoding("GBK"));
            String line = sr.ReadToEnd();
            Window.MSG("Socket", "Feed login: " + line, MessageType.SystemMessage);
        }
        catch (SocketException e)
        {
            Window.MSG("Socket", "Socket Exception: " + e.Message, MessageType.Error);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

The above code works fine, then I wrote a Netty client like below:

```
public void start() throws Exception {
    EventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup();
    try {
        Bootstrap bootstrap = new Bootstrap();
        bootstrap.group(group).channel(NioSocketChannel.class)
                .remoteAddress(new InetSocketAddress(host, port))
                .handler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                    @Override
                    public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch)
                            throws Exception {
                        ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();
                        pipeline.addLast("lengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder",
                                new LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder(
                                        Integer.MAX_VALUE, 0, 4, 0, 4));
                        /*
                        pipeline.addLast("gzipdeflater", ZlibCodecFactory
                                .newZlibDecoder(ZlibWrapper.GZIP)); */

                        pipeline.addLast("decoder", new StringDecoder(
                                Charset.forName("gbk")));
                        pipeline.addLast("encoder", new StringEncoder());
                        pipeline.addLast("handler", new FeedClientHandler());

                    }
                });
        ChannelFuture future = bootstrap.connect().sync();
        future.channel().writeAndFlush(login);
        Thread.sleep(600000); // todo
    } finally {
        group.shutdownGracefully();
    }
}
```

This netty client is not working, and can't get any output, I debugged and found the LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder.decode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf in) method returns null because in.readableBytes < frameLengthInt  (in.readableBytes = 1028, frameLengthInt = 1882716544).

I have no idea how to get it work, any suggestions? thanks in advance : )

Comment: What's the endianness of the length field?

Comment: Try pass 1st arg to LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder your byte order ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN

Comment: @trustin, thanks for your guidance, you pointed me to the right direction.

Comment: @Suvitruf, your solution works, it saved me a lot of time, many thanks!

Comment: @sumlight, cool! Please consider self-answering this question. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to trustin and Suvitruf's comment, after setting the LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder's ByteOrder as LITTLE_ENDIAN, the client works!

```
pipeline.addLast("lengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder", new LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN, Integer.MAX_VALUE, 0, 4, 0, 4, true));
```